# Avoid the conflict on port 80 between nodejs and apache

Tags: apache, node.js, port, express

The goal is to listen on port 80 with nodejs without killing apache.

I have to say my knowledges in network are very basic.

UPDATE

I am trying to use `ProxyPass` `ProxyPassReverse` on my local machine but there is something wrong.

```
    Alias /test /media/www-dev/public/test
    <Directory /media/www-dev/public/test>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ProxyRequests off

   <Proxy *>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
   </Proxy>
   <Location />
     ProxyPass /test http://localhost:3000/
     ProxyPassReverse /test http://localhost:3000/
   </Location>
```

When i launch `http://localhost/test` on my browser i get a message `Cannot GET /test/`, if i stop to listen on the port 3000, then i get 503 `Service Temporarily Unavailable` my node app is listening on the port 3000.

If if commente the "Proxy" lines, i can reach the URL `http://localhost/test` again.

Why can i not access the URL `http://localhost/test` ? Is it because the proxy try to reach `http://localhost:3000/` instead following the path of the alias /test ?

Thanks !

Comment: I think you need to use apache as a proxy, that forwards request to your node app on localhost:8080 or something similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to create a virtual host in apache for your node app and proxy over the requests.

here is what mine looks like in /etc/apache/sites-available/dogself.com

```
<VirtualHost 69.164.218.75:80>
    ServerName dogself.com
    ServerAlias www.dogself.com
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/dogself.com/public_html/
    ErrorLog /srv/www/dogself.com/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /srv/www/dogself.com/logs/access.log combined

    ProxyRequests off

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    <Location />
        ProxyPass http://localhost:3000/
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000/
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

It sounds like you have a lot to research before you can get this working though. start reading docs

Comment: I think i understand this code, but it doesn't work on my side, when i add the `Location` balises i get an `Internal Server Error` in my local machine visiting any localhost routes.

Comment: After adding the proxy_http mod to apache i get `Service Temporarily Unavailable` trying to reach localhost

Comment: good luck. there can be so many reasons for this, but most likely your node app is not responding on localhost:3000

Comment: Yes i finally made it works stuying further the apache doc, thanks everybody !

Comment: @Ludo How do you fix it? I alse encounter `Internal Server Error`

Comment: @Ludo fix it with `a2enmod  proxy_http`,sorry for brothering.
And @mkoryak perhaps you would better edit to append the `a2enmod  proxy_http` for people like me not familiar with apache

Answer (score 2):

Alternative approach for a virtual host would be the following

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin info@DOMAIN.com
    ServerName DOMAIN.com
    ServerAlias www.DOMAIN.com
    ProxyRequests off

    <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    <Location />
            ProxyPass http://localhost:3000/
            ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000/
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

To fix the Internal Server ERROR just enable the right apache extension.

```
sudo a2enmod proxy_http
sudo service apache2 restart
```